# How to optimise SQL query execution time

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

Below is my SQL query which contains five inner joins. It takes 10 minutes to execute. How can we optimise this query to run faster?

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.assesmt_no,
                a.parcel_no,
                vi.struct_no,
                om.own_first AS TaxpayerName
FROM assessments a
INNER JOIN owner om ON om.id = a.owner_id
INNER JOIN valueimp vi ON vi.assesmt_no = a.assesmt_no
INNER JOIN imp_details imp ON imp.improvementId = vi.id
INNER JOIN imp_components_details impdt ON impdt.quality_id = imp.quality_id
INNER JOIN category_items ci ON ci.category_id = impdt.category_id
WHERE ci.category_id <> 3
```

Comment: Make sure there are indexes on the tables. Run the execution plan on the query that should help you figure out where the query is slow.

Comment: Maybe <>3. Try instead IN operator. Like category_id in (2,4,7)

Comment: Post actual execution plan in xml.

Comment: what is the data volume of this query and which table is holding huge data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All joins that multiply rows may be transformed into `exists`, after that you'll be able to abandon `distinct`. `category_id <> 3` makes it unable to do something else than `scan` unless most of rows have `category_id=3` and only few of them `<>`.

So, without DDL and additional info my guess is:

```
select 
    a.assesmt_no, a.parcel_no, vi.struct_no, om.own_first as TaxpayerName
from assessments a
inner join owner om on om.id = a.owner_id
inner join valueimp vi on vi.assesmt_no = a.assesmt_no
where exists(
    select 1
    from imp_details imp 
    inner join imp_components_details impdt on impdt.quality_id = imp.quality_id
    inner join category_items ci on ci.category_id = impdt.category_id
    where imp.improvementId = vi.id
        and ci.category_id <> 3
)
```

And I'm afraid nothing else is possible to do with it.

Comment: That is a very nice guess against my guess.

Comment: Its not a guess. This won't make much difference and you are just making a guess.

Comment: Well, I'd recommend to review documentation about `DISTINCT` and what additional operations it requires, about `EXISTS` and what optimization possibilities it provides, to try executing some queries and reviewing different **execution plans**.

Answer (score 0):

Please add `option (hash join,hash group)` at the end of your query

---

P.s.

1. Is the join with `imp_details` and `imp_components_details` necessary?
   Is it for filtering purposes ?
2. Why do you expect to see duplicates (and therefore using `distinct`?

Comment: That's quite an assumption to make, not knowing how many records are in each table, what indexes currently exist, or what particular operators the query has picked

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, would you like to make a bet on 100 reputation scores?

Comment: No I prefer measurements, benchmarking and information over bets. But I'll bet you back that the question is abandoned like most others! :). I mean what if the query happens to have a bunch of awesome clustered indexes, making merge the best operator every time

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, sadly, you are probably right, but I haven't lost hope yet in the humanity of OPs. As for the issue itself, after some deducting everything is actually pretty clear. When the OP hopefully will attach the execution plan we are going to see nested loop joins.

Comment: Maybe but why would a hash join be better than a nested join? again without knowing the proportion of rows in each table. The SQL Engine can usually come up with the right query plan. Anyway lets see I'm always willing to learn